# Struggling with identifying distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

I am being asked to identify the following distribution and then workout the mean and variance:

$$f(x) \propto x^4e^{8x}$$

It looks like a Poisson distribution but I am struggling with understanding how to get it into a poison probability mass function form. I know how to workout the mean and variance once I get it into the form I need.

Comment: If you find the normalizing constant, it will give you big hints.

Comment: What is $f$'s support?

Comment: @J.G. I haven't been given a support so I am assuming it is defined for all natural numbers.

Comment: @DavGRoz That doesn't work. If $f$ is a pmf (pdf) up to scaling, the sum (integral) of $f$ over its support must be finite.

Comment: Update- I didn't realise this was infact a gamma distribution. Apologies!

Comment: @DavGRoz it could be a Gamma distribution's PDF up to scaling, if you meant to include a $-$ sign in the exponent; $\tfrac{8^5}{4!}x^4e^{-8x}$ is a PDF on $[0,\,infty)$.